# Inserting node at the beginning of a linked list - python implementation

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a method to the Linked_List class, which should insert a value at the beginning of the linked list. However the inserted value is None and I just can't see what am I missing? Any help will be appreciated!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
    
class Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()

    def display(self):
        elements = []
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next != None:
            cur_node = cur_node.next
            elements.append(cur_node.data)
        return elements

    def insertNodeAtBegining(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertion at beginning is right but your display method is wrong, the way you traversing a linked list is wrong, after checking `curr_node.next` is not None , you should take node value and add it to elements but you are forwarding to next node and adding that value, this skipping  0th element always.

Below is code to traverse a linked list

```
def display(self):

    curr_node = self.head
    elements = []

    if curr_node is None:
        return elements

    while curr_node:
         elements.append(curr_node.data)
         curr_node = curr_node.next

    return elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your `insertNodeAtBegining` method. As I see you have some logical error in `display` function. Let's say you have only 1 element in linked-list, with current implementation of `display`, it would check that `next` node is `None` and would not add element in `elements` list.
First check if you have valid head node and add element, then check for `next` node and etc.

It should look something like this:

```
def display(self):
    elements = []
    cur_node = self.head
    while True:
        if cur_node.data:
            elements.append(cur_node.data)

        if cur_node.next != None:
            cur_node = cur_node.next
        else:
            break

    return elements
```